# When does copy(foo) call foo.copy?

Tags: python, copy

I'm designing a base class, and I want it to define a base behaviour for `copy.copy`.
This behaviour consists in printing a warning in the console, and then copying the instance as if it had no `__copy__` attribute.

When one defines a blank `Foo` class and copies an instance of it, the `copy` function returns a new instance of that class, as shown by the following session:

```
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo2 = copy(foo)
>>> foo is foo2
False
```

Now if the `Foo` class defines a `__copy__` instance method, the latter will be called when trying to pass an instance to `copy`:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __copy__(self):
...         print("Copying")
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> copy(foo)
Copying
```

So as I understand it, the flow of execution of the `copy` function would be:

1. Try to access the object's `__copy__` attribute
2. If present, call it
3. If absent, perform a generic copy

But now, I want to capture the `copy` function's accessing the `__copy__` attribute, through defining a `__getattr__` method, and then simulate the absence of this attribute, by raising an `AttributeError`:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __getattr__(self, attr):
...         if attr == '__copy__':
...             print("Accessing '__copy__'")
...             raise AttributeError
...
```

Then the `__copy__` attribute does not seem to be accessed anymore:

```
>>> foo = Foo()

# Actual behaviour of copy(foo)
>>> copy(foo)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\copy.py", line 96, in copy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

# Expected behaviour of copy(foo)
>>> foo.__copy__()
Accessing '__copy__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __getattr__
AttributeError
```

What am I missing in the execution flow of the `copy` function, with regards to the `__copy__` attribute?

As far as I understand, given a `foo` object with no attribute `bar`, it should behave exactly the same, whether it has a `__getattr__` method that fails on `bar`, or it doesn't define anything.
Is this statement exact?

Comment: it seems that even `__getattribute__` is not called when the copy module tries to look for `__copy__` because it acts on the class your object, not your object itself (bypass)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's indeed what that infamous [`line 96 in copy`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/copy.py) looks like... So it's the class that should implement `__getattr__`?

Comment: except that `__getattr__` isn't a class method. I think you could [edit] your question for a better [mcve], not involving the `copy` module at all but only the `getattribute` on the class.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Couldn't it be? For instance, if I changed `Foo`'s metaclass... Meh, that doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre But it turns out to be a plain different question... I'll think of it, and if I can't find a solution, I'll ask a question.

Comment: I've posted an answer. It's my technical advice, and I think I'm right, but if others have better to propose, I'll accept the downvotes :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think you're right, although that answer disappoints me somehow ^^ Thanks for helping me in my reflexion!

Comment: let's not lose hope. Maybe someone will have a better idea or a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer seems to be "no".

Within the `copy.copy` method we find this (summarized)

```
cls = type(x)

...

copier = getattr(cls, "__copy__", None)
```

We see that the function uses `getattr` on the *class*, not the *instance*.

And there's no way to have `__getattr__` called when `getattr` is called on the *class* (just because it's an *instance* method)

Demo (sorry, I would have prefered a working demo)

```
class Foo:
    def __getattr__(self,attr):
             if attr == '__copy__':
                     return "WORKED"

foo = Foo()
print(getattr(foo, "__copy__",None))
print(getattr(Foo, "__copy__",None))
```

this returns:

```
WORKED
None
```

So it's not possible to fool the original `copy.copy` module into believing there's a `__copy__` attribute without creating a `__copy__` method.

Comment: I suppose you meant `__getattr__`, rather than `__getattribute__`?

Comment: @Rightleg yeah. Both behave the same in that case, though.